# What groups are that? What does : mean?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, notation

What are the groups 2^6 : 3 . S_6 or 2^4 : A_8 ? Are they some subgroups of S_6 or A_8?

I believe that 2 . A_n is the double cover of A_n, and "multiplying" with a number gives a covering group. But what does : stand for?

I read Pinter "A Book of Abstract Algebra" (that's my level, the notation appears in more advanced texts). Any suggestions where this notation is explained?

Thank you

Comment: . is "times". So the dot should be in the middle between 3 and S_6.

Comment: These two groups come up when explaining the Mathieu groups (which I'm trying to understand), for example in Wilson "The simple finite groups" section 5.2 or in Conway/ Sloane "Sphere packing.." in chapter 11.

Comment: Where are you seeing this notation? If it's in Pinter's book, what page, what edition?

Comment: Explanations for the notation can be found in the introduction to "An Atlas of Finite Groups"

Answer (score 2):

This is ATLAS notation.

The : means a split extension, and $2^4$ means an elementary abelian group of that order. So $2^4:A_8$ denotes a group $G$ having an elementary abelian normal subgroup $N$ of order $16$ and a subgroup $H \cong A_8$ such that $G = NH$ and $N \cap H = 1$. So $G  \cong N \rtimes A_8$. We can also deduce that the action of $A_8$ on $N$ is nontrivial, since otherwise it would be a direct product written as $2^4 \times A_8$.

In principal the bracketing of $2^6:3\cdot S_6$ is ambiguous but the only sensible interpretation is $2^6:(3 \cdot S_6)$, which denotes a group $G \cong N \rtimes H$ with $N$ elementary abelian of order $64$ and $H \cong 3 \cdot S_6$, a 3-fold cover of $S_6$. The $\cdot$ actually denotes a nonsplit extension.